# Missing ENABLE_WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING value in DatabaseOpenFlags for OpenDatabase method

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-sqlite

Why Xamarin Android.Database.Sqlite.DatabaseOpenFlags Enumeration does not expose enum value for java ENABLE_WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bug, it is missing from the `enum-conversion-mappings.xml` file:

```
<map package='android.database.sqlite' class='SQLiteDatabase' fields='OPEN_READWRITE OPEN_READONLY CREATE_IF_NECESSARY NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS' enum-name='DatabaseOpenFlags' is-transient='false' />
```

Re: [enum-conversion-mappings.xml Line 717](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/e33eb53407bc85f0b9a0f6c41d9ec009371eedcc/build-tools/enumification-helpers/enum-conversion-mappings.xml#L717)

I reported it: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60465